# Customize Woocommerce login page

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have created a login page in elementor and I want to replace that layout to my account page login form layout of woocommerce.

[image]

This is a default login form of woocommerce.

[image]

This is a customized form in elementor but the url of this form is [www.example.com/login](http://www.example.com/login). I just want to replace this design with example.com/my-account login form layout without changing url.
How to do that?

Comment: The enter image description here an image url. sorry by mistake the name was changed

Comment: Hi Rakesh, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you edit your question to make it as clear as possible and include any code or images inline please.